# Javascript: Using IF condition with imgTmp

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The script below works. However, I would like to use it along with a conditional IF statement to say "If the state is Online, then `changeIt.style.visibility = 'visible';` else/if not then `changeIt.style.visibility = 'hidden';`

I really tried, but didn't manage to use IF with imgTmp.

```
function checkimage() {
    var imgTmp = new Image();
    imgTmp.onload = function() {
        printState("Online");
    };
    imgTmp.onerror = function() {
        printState("Offline");
    };
    imgTmp.src = "http://xxx/test.png?_=" + (+new Date());
}

function printState(state) {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = " + state + ";
}

printState();
    setInterval(checkimage, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your printState or, create other function to change the something you want visibility...

```
function printState(state) {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = " + state + ";
    if (state === 'Online') {
        changeIt.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        changeIt.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```